# I want listView suggestions over the same page in flutter

Tags: dictionary, listview, flutter

Hey guys I want to make an dictionary app
Which will show list suggestions over the screen (not taking over another page for that)
Can anyone help please

Comment: I think you need to add more details of what you're trying to achieve (with some screenshots) as well as your current code/what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree you need to share more so I understand that you need to something like [typehead](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead) library, you can check that.